# Sync MAMP db via Wlan

Tags: mysql, database, macos, synchronization, mamp

I sync my work files between my iMac and my MB Air with a automatic sync tool as soon as I enter my wlan.

Now I'd like to also sync my local MAMP Webdev environement.
I tried to sync my whole MAMP folder but this led to a world of pain and dispair, like someone mentioned here that this isn't a good Idea.

Now I had another Idea:
Is there some sort of automated db-export script, so I could just sync the .sql file and let it automaticly reimport it on my other computer.

Does something like this exist:

Thanks for any help.

Comment: its really easy to make something, all you would have to do is have a cron that runs every 30 minutes and checks to see if a device with the local ip of, for example: "192.168.0.11", and once it spots it , it makes a call to a script on that device that is broadcasting out and all that script would do is export all the databases and upload it to the other device that was seeking it. This can all be created with php very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this on a case-by case basis using the command line, i have 100s of tables on my machines :)

You could create two sh scripts; export.sh

```
%pathtomysqlbin%/mysqldump -u%admin% -p$adminpw% --all-databases > tmpfile.sql
```

and import.sh

```
%pathtomysqlbin%/mysql -u%admin% -p%adminpw < tmpfile.sql
```

Then tell your sync tool to execute the export.sh script before starting and finally - manually run the import.sh when you start working on the other computer :)